# Opera fullscreen window is resized when macOS top menu bar is shown

Tags: macos, opera

I guess the post title is pretty explicit, but I add two little GIFs links to illustrate the problem I'm encountering.
This is quite annoying since it causes visual disruptance.

On Safari, Firefox or Chrome, the top menu bar is overlapping the software window, without resizing it. I should note that I also encountered this issue on the new Edge Dev (Chromium), so I suspect it might be a Chromium issue and I really wonder what causes this because on a friend's MacBook Pro, it doesn't happen.

**Resize behavior (Opera / Edge chromium) :** https://s5.gifyu.com/images/Hnet.com-image.gif

**Expected behavior (Firefox / Safari / Chrome...) :** https://s5.gifyu.com/images/firefox.gif

Does anyone have an idea on this ?

Comment: Is this on macOS 10.15 Catalina? This is true only for Chromium based browsers and Safari. Mozilla Firefox has the expected behaviour. Your friend's Macbook Pro probably has different macOS version.

Comment: I had this on Sierra, High Sierra, and this issue is still present on Catalina.